# Save as .pdf extention for Office 2003

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2003

For Office 2003, does it support the Save As `.pdf` plug-in (free) as found in Office 2007?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I have hear of.

But you can install something like [PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)

> The Bullzip PDF Printer works as a Microsoft Windows printer and allows you to write PDF documents from virtually any Microsoft Windows application.
>
> This program is FREEWARE with limitations, which means that it is FREE for personal and commercial use up to 10 users. It does not contain any advertising or popups. For commercial applications with more that 10 users there is a commercial version of the product available at www.biopdf.com.

[Some other alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/searchresult.aspx?search=PDF%20Printer)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en // I think this will work.  Its for a custom-web application that we built that uses Word and Excel '07 as its reporting service.  Problem is, any User running 2003 was incompatible.  This may prove to be the solution though.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I use [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) for 3 years, it's an opensource project.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could combine pdf-t-maker and pdfcreator to do the trick, if you w pdfant a nicely structured PDF with things like a table of contents or links.